# Update a cell value in 1 Excel link

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Update a cell value in an Excel link

I have 1 workbook which contains 2 tabs: sheet_1 & sheet_2

I have 1 page sheet_1 which contains several links which all lead to sheet_2 (another tab in the same workbook).

I would like that when I click on 1 of these links (which is on sheet_1), I can modify the value of B2 (which is on sheet_2).

Without vbA code, is it possible to change 1 value of a cell in an Excel hyperlink?
Knowing that each link gives 1 different value to B2.
If I click on link_1, b2= value received in link_1
If I click on link_2, b2= value received in link_2

Thanks a lot for your help.

try with hyperlink function but I can't give 1 argument to my link to tell it sheet!B2 = link_B2

With 1 screenshot, it will be more telling I think.

[Screenshot_Sheet_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFb2T.png)

[Screenshot_Sheet_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4PBe.png)

Comment: If you put the formula `=Sheet1!A1` in cell "A1" of Sheet2, then the value of that cell in Sheet2 will change every time you change the value of "A1" in Sheet1. Is this what you want?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with `links`. Best post your formular or a screenshot

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I added 2 screenshots. Let me know if my problem is clearer. In cell B2 (Sheet_2 tab), I would like to retrieve the value based on the selected link.  So I want to know if it is possible in the link that redirects from Sheet_1 to Sheet_2 if we can include variables (change the value of B2 in the Sheet_2 tab)

Comment: This is an intriguing challenge, but absent VBA, I can't see any way to do this.